# C++11: std::bind crashes with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why does this code crash?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::function<void(int)> function = [](int)
    {
    };
    auto binding = std::bind(function, 10);

    std::function<void()> jobFunctor = binding; // crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    return 0;
}
```

When converting the result of the bind to `jobFunctor` there is an infinite stack recursion in a `std::function` constructor.

I am running Mac OS X 10.8.5, I compile this code with Xcode 5.0.2 using libc++, the compiler version:

```
LO50F-04-198BX:$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Doesn't crash on gcc 4.8 and clang 3.4 on linux or gcc 4.8.1 on windows.

Comment: This also crashes under OS X 10.9.1. In this case the segmentation fault is due to overflowing the stack with an infinite number of recursive function calls within std::bind.

Comment: It should work fine: http://ideone.com/GXGIBx

Comment: it appears to be a compiler bug

Comment: debug it?  Maybe that can produce a clue.

Comment: Actually, it crashes even without the last line of code, i.e. it crashes while executing the line with the `bind`. Same compiler as Piotr, but Target x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

Comment: @Yakk Feel free to compile that code yourself and see what the backtrace looks like and then say that again ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that this code should work, and that it is a defect in the implementation of libc++.

I've posted a bug report for you on the libc++ bug tracker. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18282

**Edit:** And as Casey has pointed out, this has already been fixed in libc++. Now you'll simply need to wait for Apple to release an updated version of libc++ in some forthcoming version of XCode / OS X.

Comment: @Casey: I think you are correct. Sadly, my searches came up with nothing.

Comment: @Casey: Especially when you look at the test case associated with that bug, it's pretty clear that they are referring to the same thing. [The test case they added can be found here](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/utilities/function.objects/bind/func.bind/func.bind.bind/copy.pass.cpp?view=markup&pathrev=185297).